# Strange behavior with Kernel.spawn and rails in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spawn

If I add the following lines in `application.rb`

```
puts 'in application.rb'
pid = spawn('rake jobs:work')
Process.detach pid
```

I see the following output

```
in application.rb
=> Booting Puma
...
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
in application.rb
[Worker(host:local pid:9966)] Starting job worker
in application.rb
[Worker(host:local pid:9998)] Starting job worker
in application.rb
[Worker(host:local pid:10032)] Starting job worker
```

If I remove the `spawn` call `in application.rb` is displayed only once at the beginning, as expected.

This output is written at about once per second. All those processes are healthy and will be stoped when I killed puma.

I can't figure out what is happening. Why is this code getting executed every second?

Answer (score 2):

... rake is also requiring the file, that's why.

To get this to work as expected:

```
if $0 =~ /rails/
  pid = spawn('rake jobs:work')
  Process.detach pid
end
```